# play musics According to positions item of list

Tags: android

I want played musics According to item of list for example if clicked on Forty items,played Forty musics
Im use from followin code but only played First music.
Where is the problem??
this is my activity:

```
int intArray[] = {R.raw.alaa,R.raw.basemtavasol};
.
.
.
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Faslha fasl = faslha.get(position);
    Intent next = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    next.putExtra("my_array", intArray);
    next.putExtra("thisfasl", fasl);
    startActivity(next);

}
.
.
.
```

this is Second Activity:

```
.
.
.
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 int[] arrayInB = extras.getIntArray("my_array");
 songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb);
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, arrayInB[0]);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting why you are starting another activity. Instead of calling activity directly 
Run Media player.

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,"your path");
         mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
         mMediaPlayer.start();
```